# React Router Animated Transitions On Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm exploring Routes animation and basic example works perfectly. But in case of using redirect inside animated Route component it is crashed with infinitive render loop.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/v3j736jvwl

Reproduce: Press Redirect link

It works without animation if I remove location props on Switch component:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/redirect" component={RedirectToMain} />
    <Route exact path="/hsl/:h/:s/:l" component={HSL} />
    <Route exact path="/rgb/:r/:g/:b" component={RGB} />
    <Route render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
  </Switch>
```

I expect an animation of page redirect without crashing.

Answer (score 0):

U can't use redirect link to redirect inside redirected component. Instead use something like this:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/v3j736jvwl

```
class RedirectToMain extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          ...styles.fill,
          ...styles.hsl,
          background: `red`
        }}
      >
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```